# How to show 20 static xml layouts through a single activity?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

I have 20 xml layouts which i have to show in order. They are static and does not contain any updates or operations as such. All i want to have is a next button in each layout and just display them one by one when the next button is clicked. 
My question is can i accomplish that with a single activity? Or will i have to make 20 corrs activities to accompany it??

PS: I can name the layouts anything if it can help to put them in some loop or something. Thanx in advance for any help.

Comment: I think you are looking for view pager http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/

Answer (score 2):

i think u can use ViewFlipper for that.

```
ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);

//Inflate the Views
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.t1, null);
View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.t2, null);
View v3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.t3, null);

//Add the views to the flipper
viewFlipper.addView(v1);
viewFlipper.addView(v2);
viewFlipper.addView(v3);

//Move between them
flipper.showNext();
flipper.showPrevious();
```

Answer (score 0):

no, you don't need new activities. Just call `setContentView(R.layout.thenextlayout)`, but there are better ways to do this and design things depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) together with [replace()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29). If you are not familiar with fragments consider using [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html).